# Changing a partition with fdisk shows a warning like "partition#x contains ext4-signature"

Tags: filesystems, partitioning, partition, ext4

I'm shrinking a partion size with

```
#Reduce Partition Size
fsck -f /dev/sdb2
resize2fs /dev/sdb2 -M -p

#Limit Partion
fdisk /dev/sdb
... #Now I'm changing the Partition 2 to the new (smaller) size
```

fdisk gives me a (red) warning like `partition#2 contains ext4-signature` (`Partition #2 enthält eine ext4-Signatur`)

Is there something wrong? Why does the fdisk show me a warning?

Answer (score 13):

I tried to found the same.
So it means there're EXT4 fs on this partition.
For example, on partition and FS increasing this warning appears to. Just select "N" if you don't plan to remove fs.

```
Created a new partition 1 of type 'Linux' and of size 100 GiB.
Partition #1 contains an ext4 signature.

Do you want to remove the signature? [Y]es/[N]o: N
```

Most complete answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/477991/what-is-a-vfat-signature/478001#478001